# How does a contact and Legal Entity related in Person Account Salesforce?

Tags: salesforce, crm

I have trouble understanding an aspect of Person Accounts in Salesforce. I have both Business and Person accounts (with different record types) in Salesforce. When I create a contact from the related list of a business Account I do see a person account & Contact created but it is NOT related to business Account in any way. Can someone explain if this is the expected behavior ?

Answer (score 0):

Person Account is a contact and account at the same time. It should be used when an account is not an organization but an individual. For example your cable company will have you listed as a Person Account but create Account with related Contacts say for an Hospital.
More on this you can read [in this pdf](https://eu3.salesforce.com/help/pdfs/en/salesforce_B2C_implementation_guide.pdf)